Higher order Laplacian-like operators
We have the second order differential operator Laplacian for sphere $\Delta=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\partial_\theta(\sin\theta\partial_\theta) + \cot^{\;2}\theta {\partial_\phi}^2$ and for plane $\Delta={\partial_x}^2+{\partial_y}^2$, which is invariant under the symmetry group of the space, rotation for the sphere, rotation and translation for the plane. Are there higher order differential operator analogs? Not restricted to the sphere or the plane, consider any space that possesses some symmetry group. Also only irreducible ones, which cannot be decomposed as product of lower order operators.

Interesting question. As with regards to the irreducibility of your differential operators, could you perhaps expand on that, considering them as elements in a non-commutative ring. I understand that you want to discard polyharmonic equations and the like.

@undefined Thank you for your interest. I would say an operator $O$ has symmetry $S$ if for any function $f$ we have $O(S f)=S(O f)$, by this definition the products and sums of operators with symmetry $S$ are also operators with the same symmetry. By irreducible I do mean the operator cannot be decomposed into sum or product of other operators with same symmetry. You are correct I want to rule out, for example, powers of the Laplacian.
